# How to add a new input field at click of button Spring/Java/Thymeleaf

Tags: java, spring, forms, input

Very new to Java, have a form created with Thymeleaf and Spring. I need a way to insert new input text field if a button is clicked. Any idea how to make this happen? I think I need to do something in the @RequestMapping/Controller file. But also, how do I generate a new input line, do I need to define something extra in the Model?
This is the button...

```html
        <!-- add option for user to add another input line -->
        <div class="row text-right">
            <label>Add another input line</label>
            <button type="submit" name="addInputLine" class="btn btn-default" ><span class="fa fa-plus"></span></button>
        </div>
```

Comment: Sounds more like you need a Javascript [onclick handler](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onclick) for the button click to add the new input.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to use Javascript for this and do it on the frontend.

An example using raw javascript, first add an id to the parent element and give the button a click handler:

```
<div id="parentElement" class="row text-right">
    <label>Add another input line</label>
    <button onclick="addInputLine()" name="addInputLine" class="btn btn-default" ><span class="fa fa-plus"></span></button>
</div>
```

Next add the javascript function for the click handler

```
<script>
function addInputLine() {
var node = document.createElement("input");                 // Create an <input> node                         
document.getElementById("parentElement").appendChild(node);     // Append it to the parent
}
</script>
```

In the long run you'll probably be better off looking at frameworks such as jquery to handle this kind of thing